# How do you search two MySQL Table/Rows at the same time and return two separate results?

Tags: php, mysql

**FUNCTION OF SCRIPT** : To allow users to search for artist name or song title

**Benefit to other users** : script can be easily modified for other stackoverflow users to work and search their sites - just change the query to your database structure.

```
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM lyrics WHERE title LIKE '%%%s%%' ORDER BY title ASC", $colname_Recordset1);
```

**ISSUE with script** : It works for song title, but I do not understand how to make it search for Artist name and Song title at the same time without using a dropdown that changes the search. Also returns error upon no result(s)

An example of artist (Rihanna - id : 16689) (title : Unfaithful - id : 228106)
http://www.thelyricsfinder.com/song.php?sid=228106&aid=16689

[Live/Working Example of Search.php](http://thelyricsfinder.com/search.php)

- Received error output upon no results (below)

..

> ERROR :
>  
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

```
$maxRows_Recordset1 = 100;
$pageNum_Recordset1 = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_Recordset1'])) {
  $pageNum_Recordset1 = $_GET['pageNum_Recordset1'];
}
$startRow_Recordset1 = $pageNum_Recordset1 * $maxRows_Recordset1;

$colname_Recordset1 = "-1";
if (isset($_POST['term'])) {
  $colname_Recordset1 = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_POST['term'] : addslashes($_POST['term']);
}
mysql_select_db($database_main, $main);
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM lyrics WHERE title LIKE '%%%s%%' ORDER BY title ASC", $colname_Recordset1);
$query_limit_Recordset1 = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_Recordset1, $startRow_Recordset1, $maxRows_Recordset1);
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_limit_Recordset1, $main) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_Recordset1'])) {
  $totalRows_Recordset1 = $_GET['totalRows_Recordset1'];
} else {
  $all_Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1);
  $totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($all_Recordset1);
}
$totalPages_Recordset1 = ceil($totalRows_Recordset1/$maxRows_Recordset1)-1;
```

**OBJECTIVE** : To make the script search two table/rows from the single search being passed to $_POST['term'] BUT THE KICKER return the results into two separate variables for separate display.

1. ARTIST/artist
2. LYRICS/title

thanks for helping me find how to do this. back to the books to try to get the answer.

ADDED 11/2/2012 (I know I can help fix part of the issue by adding no results found handling below thanks for the help below guys, now I need to learn how to do the two queries at once)

Comment: Make an echo to the query and see what it returns.

Comment: The error you have is not because you have more than two words. You will get this error for all searches that have no results (try searching 'aaaa', you'll get the error). Your code need to handle the no-results case.

Comment: Not related to your error... but you're concatenating user input `'term'` into your SQL statement. This means you're vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  You should be using prepared statements - there's some PHP package to do that but I forget the name, not being a PHP programmer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to have a separate process for empty result query. Since the issue is not the "more than two words" but when the search result is empty. Try something like this

```
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_limit_Recordset1, $main) or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1 );
if($num_rows == 0){
   //error message
}
else{
   //process here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just searched `Fool on the hill`, which is more than two words and it worked. And then `Fill on the bill` gave the error that you are speaking about.

`ERROR :
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`

It just means that you need to handle the empty rows returned case, when the search term matches no record in the database.